# Use multiple conditions in join LINQ. i,e AND

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

How to use multiple condition in LINQ joins, i.e. in my scenario I need to get all the users from table User where group ID = 4 from table UserInGroup, where UserInGroup is intermediate table between User and Group table as in SQL-T we use join as

```
select * 
from user 
where user.userID = userIngroup.userID AND userIngroup.groupID == 4
....
```

In another approach I am using lambda expression along with LINQ, how I can apply where groupID = 4 in following one??

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersByGroupID(int _groupID)
    {

        List<User> _listedUsersByGroupID = new List<User>();

        using(var _uow = new UserManagement_UnitOfWork())
        {

            _listedUsersByGroupID = (from _users in _uow.User_Repository.GetAll()
                                    .Include(s=>s.UserInGroup.Select(r=>r.Group))
                                    select _users).ToList();

            return _listedUsersByGroupID;

        }
    }
```

### User Model

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public User() { }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserInGroup> UserInGroup { get; set; }
}
```

### UserInGroup Model

```
 [Table("UserInGroup")]
public class UserInGroup
{
    public UserInGroup() { }

    [Key]
    public int UserGroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

### Group Model

```
public class Group
{
    public Group() { }

    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserInGroup> UserInGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add a condition to filter the users that belong to the group 4. Try this:

```
  _listedUsersByGroupID = (from _user in _uow.User_Repository.GetAll()
                                    .Include(s=>s.UserInGroup.Select(r=>r.Group))
                           where user.UserInGroup.Any(ug=>ug.groupID==4)
                           select _user).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda query would look something like:

```
ctx.User.Where(user=>
    ctx.UserInGroup.Any(userIngroup=>
        user.userID == userIngroup.userID && userIngroup.groupID == 4
    )
)
```

That however is just query, if you want to get results add **.AsList()** or **.AsEnumerable()** to end.

---

However you can write silly and inefficient code if you do not fully understand what you are doing. I would reccomend you try this instead:

```
var publications = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<UserResults>(String.Format(@"
    select UserID, FirstName,LastName,Age,EmailAddress,UserInGroup    
    from user 
    where user.userID = userIngroup.userID AND userIngroup.groupID == {0}
    order by UserID
", Config.Group));
```

Where **Config.Group** is 4; **UserResults** can be **User** table as well, if you do not want other fields. You need to execute or enumerate over the sql query to use the data and like before you can use **.AsList()** or **.AsEnumerable()** for that.

---

Variable **ctx** is database context. For example:

```
using (var ctx = new toxicEntities())
{

}
```